# Sonar dashboard not showing the score for code smells

Tags: sonarqube

Looking at the sonar dashboard I thought everything is fine because I have 'A' ratings for Bugs, Vulnerabilities and Debt.

[image: Sonarqube dashboard with different ratings]

However then I checked the "Code Smells" in the issues view, and there are lots of unresolved issues in there, some with high severities:

[image: number of issues with severities]

I looked at the [definition](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions) of the Debt, but didn't find the Technical Debt Ratio anywhere in sonar. I would have expected the following view - including a rating on Code Smells:

[image: Image of how the sonarqube dashboard should look like]

So why is the rating missing for Code smells? Is that configurable? 
Where can I see the Technical Debt Ratio in sonar?

**Update**

Some clarification what I meant with the question:

For Bugs and Vulnerabilities the rating 1:1 reflects the issue situation: If there is only one Blocker (E) the rating for both categories "jums" to E (red) in the dashboard. 
For Debt category this is different. However as a product owner/manager the dashboard is an important instrument where people want to quickly view the state of the application. So in our project the developers must fix all issues above Info level (B,C,D,E). Two aspects:

1. In the project there are currently over 4314 issues which are not represented in the dashboard.
2. Since our project has a huge amount of DTO/Entity/Java Beans/Enum etc. classes which, due to their triviality contain less issues, dilute and distort the result of the debt rating.

So is it possible to activate a "Code Smell" rating in the dashboard (which has the behavior of Bugs and Vulnerabilities)? (cp. last image)?

Comment: what you've done is "update" your question with new issues and a feature request. This is not the place for feature requests, and if you want to discuss how the functionality works, you should head over to the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube).

Comment: I removed the feature request and clarified the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Technical Debt is the estimated remediation time for all Code Smells. The [Technical Debt rating](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions#MetricDefinitions-Maintainability) is about the ratio of technical debt on all open Code Smells versus the size of the code base as a whole. Since the Code Smell count and the total Debt are directly related, it would be redundant to have a rating on each number.

The Security and Reliability ratings correspond directly to the severities of the worst issues in those categories.

Why is there a difference in the two types of calculation? Because of urgency. A blocker or critical bug or vulnerability is *urgent*. It means something *is wrong*. *Now*. It should be fixed as quickly as possible. A blocker code smell, on the other hand, indicates code that is more likely than not to induce the next maintainer to screw something up, or code that *could* be wrong but could just as easily be exactly what was intended. In other words, there's no urgency.

Is it possible to add a severity-related rating to the Maintainability domain? No. The project homepage is pre-defined and not editable.

Are there issues missing from your project homepage? No. You claim to have "over 4314 issues which are not represented", but from what I can see, they are clearly represented by the "5.5k Code Smells" shown on the homepage. Because "k" in this context means "thousand".

Comment: @Lonzak I have expanded my answer to include your additional questions.

Comment: "... but from what I can see, they are clearly represented by the "5.5k Code Smells" shown on the homepage." I disagree since everybody only looks at the the green (A) rating, so everyhting seems fine. Similar to that nobody looks at the 308 Vulnerabilities which are not fixed since there is a green (A) rating next to it. "So those can only be minors" one would think. That is the same for CodeSmells 5,5K minor issues... Which is in fact not the case!